Getting Authentication error when connecting to another private repo from the github actions workflow
I'm using the self-hosted runner in the GitHub actions workflow. Facing issue when running the terraform init command. It throws the Authentication error. I'm using PAT to connect to the other repo.
  terraform:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    needs: determine_scope
    if: needs.determine_scope.outputs.deploy == 'yes'
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    env:
      TF_VAR_snowflake_account: ${{ vars.SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT }}
      TF_VAR_snowflake_username: ${{ vars.SNOWFLAKE_USERNAME }}
      TF_VAR_snowflake_role: ${{ vars.SNOWFLAKE_ROLE }}
      TF_VAR_snowflake_private_key_passphrase: ${{ secrets.SNOWFLAKE_PASSPHRASE }}
      TF_VAR_snowflake_private_key: ${{ secrets.SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY }}

    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ inputs.path }}
        
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      
      
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZ_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: JSON Parse
        id: parse
        env:
          AZJSON: ${{ secrets.AZ_CREDENTIALS }}
        run: |
          ARM_CLIENT_ID=$(echo $AZJSON | jq -r '.["clientId"]')
          ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$(echo $AZJSON | jq -r '.["clientSecret"]')
          ARM_TENANT_ID=$(echo $AZJSON | jq -r '.["tenantId"]')
          ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(echo $AZJSON | jq -r '.["subscriptionId"]')
          echo ARM_CLIENT_ID=$ARM_CLIENT_ID >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$ARM_CLIENT_SECRET >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo ARM_TENANT_ID=$ARM_TENANT_ID >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID >> $GITHUB_ENV
 
      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v3
        with:
          terraform_version: latest
        
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16'

      - name: Configure Git Credentials
        run: |
          git config --global credential.helper store
          echo "https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GIT_PAT }}@github.com" > ~/.git-credentials
        env:
          GIT_PAT: ${{ secrets.GIT_PAT }}

      - name: Terraform Init
        run: terraform init -backend-config="${{ inputs.backend_config }}"

Error:
You said:
I'm getting this error in terraform init

│ Error: Failed to download module
│ 
│   on main.tf line 124:
│  124: module "tag_associations" ***
│ 
│ Could not download module "tag_associations" (main.tf:124) source code from
│ "git::https://github.com/g/platform-terraform.git?ref=main":
│ error downloading
│ 'https://github.com/g/platform-terraform.git?ref=main': 
│ /usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into
│ '.terraform/modules/tag_associations'...
│ remote: Invalid username or password.
│ fatal: Authentication failed for
│ 'https://github.com/g/platform-terraform.git/'

When I use the Github-hosted runner (ubuntu-latest), it works fine. But when using the self-hosted runner, it throws above error.

The issue is likely caused by your self hosted runner using a different user. What does ~ resolve to?
A potential solution is to configure git this way
git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"

